# How to customize word division in CountVectorizer?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regex, ngrams, tokenization

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
>>> import numpy
>>> import pandas

>>> vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
>>> corpus1 = ['abc-@@-123','cde-@@-true','jhg-@@-hud']
>>> xtrain = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus1)
>>> xtrain
<3x6 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

>>> xtraindf = pd.DataFrame(xtrain.toarray())
>>> xtraindf.columns = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
>>> xtraindf.columns
Index(['123', 'abc', 'cde', 'hud', 'jhg', 'true'], dtype='object')
```

I see that the special characters(-@@-) are omitted and "abc" and "123" are considered seperately. But, I want "abc-@@-123" to be treated as a single word. Is it possible to achieve? If yes, how?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible if you define CountVectorizer's `token_pattern` argument.

If you're new to regular expressions, [Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) goes over how it deals with regular expressions using the `re` module (and scikit-learn uses this under the hood) and I recommend using an online regex tester like [this one](https://regex101.com/), which gives you immediate feedback on whether your pattern captures precisely what you want.

`token_pattern` expects a regular expression to define what you want the vectorizer to consider a word. An example for the string you're attempting to match would be this pattern, modified from the default regular expression that `token_pattern` uses:

`(?u)\b\w\w+\-\@\@\-\w+\b`

Applied to your example, you would do this

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(token_pattern=r'(?u)\b\w\w+\-\@\@\-\w+\b')
corpus1 = ['abc-@@-123','cde-@@-true','jhg-@@-hud']
xtrain = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus1)
xtraindf = pd.DataFrame(xtrain.toarray())
xtraindf.columns = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
```

Which returns

```
Index(['abc-@@-123', 'cde-@@-true', 'jhg-@@-hud'], dtype='object')
```

An important note here is that it will *always* expect your words to have -@@-  nested in your tokens. For instance:

```
corpus2 = ['abc-@@-123','cde-@@-true','jhg-@@-hud', 'unexpected']
xtrain = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus2)
xtraindf = pd.DataFrame(xtrain.toarray())
xtraindf.columns = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
print(xtraindf.columns)
```

Would give you

```
Index(['abc-@@-123', 'cde-@@-true', 'jhg-@@-hud'], dtype='object')
```

If you need to match words that don't have that exact special character structure, you can wrap the string of special characters in a group and use the non-matching group modifier `?:`

```
more_robust_vec = CountVectorizer(token_pattern=r'(?u)\b\w\w+(?:\-\@\@\-)?\w+\b')
xtrain = more_robust_vec.fit_transform(corpus2)
xtraindf = pd.DataFrame(xtrain.toarray())
xtraindf.columns = more_robust_vec.get_feature_names()
print(xtraindf.columns)
```

Which prints

```
Index(['abc-@@-123', 'cde-@@-true', 'jhg-@@-hud', 'unexpected'], dtype='object')
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for explaining in such a great detail. It helped me to understand the concept better. :)